# Assign the values from a list to hash elements

Tags: perl, hash

In essence, I want to name the elements of a list.

I can do this:

```
($hash{'foo'}, $hash{'bar'}, $hash{'baz'}) = listmaker;
```

but that gets rather lengthy if there are very many elements in a list.

Is there a shorter way to only name the hash once? Perhaps some variation on this:

```
%hash = ("foo" => "abc", "bar" => "def", "baz" => "ghi");
```

but with the values coming from the function `listmaker`? I'm envisioning some sort of `map` incantation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use hash slices:

```
@hash{'foo', 'bar', 'baz'} = listmaker
```

or

```
@hash{qw( foo bar baz )} = listmaker
```

Comment: @ikegami's addition is my preferred syntax as well; I should have included that from the beginning, but I wanted to keep the original example as simple as possible to highlight the hash slice syntax.